# Plotting Cartesian mesh on Sphere with SphericalPlot3D

Tags: plotting, mesh

I really want to know how to plot the Cartesian grid lines on a 2D plane onto a sphere in the context of stereographic projection. I found this image showing what I want to plot. Can anyone help me to obtain the code to plot this sphere using SphericalPlot3D and MeshFunctions?

[image: Projection]

Comment: It would help if you provided the definition of Cartesian grid lines.

Answer (score 7):

This looks like a stereographic projection to me:

```
stereo[{x_, y_}] := {
  (2 x)/(1 + x^2 + y^2),
  (2 y)/(1 + x^2 + y^2),
  (-1 + x^2 + y^2)/(1 + x^2 + y^2)}
ParametricPlot3D[
 stereo[{x, y}], {x, -2 π, 2 π}, {y, -2 π, 2 π}, 
 PlotRange -> Full, PlotTheme -> "Classic"]
```

[image: stereographic projection of the plane]